# Why does the password saved in login form is put into other JSF components of the internal pages?

Tags: jsf, passwords

I have a app JSF2/Richfaces4 with login page and many internal pages
for the normal enterprise. I don't know why, but when the user click
to save the login/password in the browser, some internal pages (3
until today) sometimes are loaded with some field autocompleted using
the same value of the password. Then, the user must clear the local
password saving to solve the problem. What do I need to do to explain
for the browser that it haven't to fill automatically these fields.

Comment: 'Auto fill' is a client side (browser) html thing. So inspect the client side html and see if you can find a cause for this happening. Then see how it should be fixed and 'backport' that to the server side xhtml/facelet/jsf components.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the form and input tag have "autocomplete=off" attribute, which seems not be honored by all browsers (as usual). 
Another way is that the user turns of the auto-completion in his browser, which you maybe cannot expect them to do.

Maybe theses link help you out.

https://gist.github.com/runspired/b9fdf1fa74fc9fb4554418dea35718fe
https://www.20spokes.com/blog/what-to-do-when-chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off-on-your-form